# Request.UrlReferrer not giving expected result

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a website that runs under https.

I'm trying to find if an internal page was the referrer to the current page, do some stuff selectively.

Here's the code that I'm testing with:

```
        if (Request.UrlReferrer != null && Request.UrlReferrer.Host == Request.Url.Host)
        {
            Response.Write(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString + "<br>");
            Response.Write(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri + "<br>");
            Response.Write(Request.Headers["Referer"] + "<br>");
        }
```

The code correctly traps internal requests however, the variables that are outputted only ever contain the base domain - `https://example.com/` and not the expected full url `https://example.com/some-page/`.

I would have thought the output would have been present or null, not partial.

It does work correctly in a non https environment.

Anyone have an idea if/how this can be fixed.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but do you know about the [Referrer Policy](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/) header? You can somewhat control the behaviour, and in some cases, only the domain name will be returned. Maybe, this is the default. Can depend on browser etc.

Comment: Yes, I recently set the policy header to strict-origin. I misread the examples - what I needed was same-origin. Now corrected and tested working. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be my misunderstanding of the referrer policy "strict-origin". It is too restrictive on internal referrals. What I needed was the slightly less strict "same-origin".

You can see this [excellent article](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/) which explains all.